Why invalid method of parent class is called?
In laravel 10 / PHP 8.2 app I made an interface class
namespace App\Library\Services\Interfaces;

use App\Models\News;
use Carbon\Carbon;

/**
* Interface of Class to calculate rating of news
*/

interface NewsRatingInterface
{
    /**
     * calculate internal rating of a news
     *
     * @param int|News $news
     *
     * @return float - calculated news internal rating
     */
    public function calc(int|News $news): float;


    /**
     * get membership mark bonus depending on creator/user membership_mark
     *
     * @return float - membership mark bonus
     */
    function getMembershipMarkBonus(): float;

    /**
     * get total comments Weight(for all time period) for 1 comment depending on creator/user membership_mark
     *
     * @return float - total comments Weight
     */
    function getTotalCommentsWeight(): float;


    /**
     * get today comments Weight(for today) for 1 comment depending on creator/user membership_mark
     *
     * @return float - today comments Weight
     */
    function getTodayCommentsWeight(): float;

    ...

and its implementation in app/Library/Services/NewsRatingForMemberUser.php :
<?php

namespace App\Library\Services;

use App\Library\Services\Interfaces\NewsRatingInterface;
use App\Models\News;

class NewsRatingForMemberUser implements NewsRatingInterface
{
    public $news;
    public $reactionsWeight = 1;
    public $commentsWeight = 1;

    /**
     * calculate internal rating of a news
     *
     * @param int|News $news
     *
     * @return float - calculated news internal rating
     */
    public function calc(int|News $news): float
    {
        \Log::info(varDump(is_int($news), ' -1 NewsRatingForMemberUser calc is_int($news)::'));
        ...
        return self::calcReactions() + self::getMembershipMarkBonus() + self::calcComments() +
               self::calcTodayComments($todayDate) + self::calcLastWeekComments($todayDate) /*$lastWeekCommentsSummary */;
    }


    /**
     * get membership mark bonus depending on creator/user membership_mark
     *
     * @return float - membership mark bonus
     */
     function getMembershipMarkBonus(): float {
         \Log::info(varDump(0, ' -1 NewsRatingForMemberUser User getMembershipMarkBonus 0::'));
        return 0; // Simple member has no any points bonus
    }

    /**
     * get total comments Weight(for all time period) for 1 comment depending on creator/user membership_mark
     *
     * @return float - total comments Weight
     */
     function getTotalCommentsWeight(): float
    {
        return 0.2;
    }


    /**
     * get today comments Weight(for today) for 1 comment depending on creator/user membership_mark
     *
     * @return float - today comments Weight
     */
    function getTodayCommentsWeight(): float {
        return 0.5;
    }

I created a third class in app/Library/Services/NewsRatingForGoldUser.php which extends NewsRatingForMemberUser :
<?php

namespace App\Library\Services;

use App\Models\News;
use App\Library\Services\NewsRatingForMemberUser;

class NewsRatingForGoldUser extends NewsRatingForMemberUser
{

    /**
     * get membership mark bonus depending on creator/user membership_mark
     *
     * @return float - membership mark bonus
     */
     function getMembershipMarkBonus(): float {
         \Log::info(varDump(50, ' -1 NewsRatingForGold User getMembershipMarkBonus 50::'));
         die("getMembershipMarkBonus - 50");
        return 50;
    }

    /**
     * get total comments Weight(for all time period) for 1 comment depending on creator/user membership_mark
     *
     * @return float - total comments Weight
     */
    function getTotalCommentsWeight(): float
    {
        die("getTotalCommentsWeight - 50");
        return parent::getTotalCommentsWeight() * 2;
    }


    /**
     * get today comments Weight(for today) for 1 comment depending on creator/user membership_mark
     *
     * @return float - today comments Weight
     */
    function getTodayCommentsWeight(): float {
        die("getLastWeekCommentsWeight - 50");
        return parent::getTodayCommentsWeight() * 2;
    }

    /**
     * get last week comments Weight(for last week) for 1 comment depending on creator/user membership_mark
     *
     * @return float - last week comments Weight
     */
    function getLastWeekCommentsWeight(): float {
        die("getLastWeekCommentsWeight - 50");
        return parent::getLastWeekCommentsWeight() * 2;
    }

}

I use model attribute in model app/Models/News.php like :
public function getRatingAttribute()
{
    $newsRatingMembershipMarkClasses =     'news_rating_membership_mark_classes' => [
        'M' => 'App\Library\Services\NewsRatingForMemberUser',
        'G' => 'App\Library\Services\NewsRatingForGoldUser',
    ];
    return (new $newsRatingMembershipMarkClasses[$this->creator->membership_mark])-> calc(news: $this->id);
}

Problem is when NewsRatingForGoldUser class is binded (field membership_mark has 'G' value) method getMembershipMarkBonus is called from NewsRatingForMemberUser,
but NOT from NewsRatingForGoldUser class (I my example above it calls die method - I do not see this message.
What is wrong with getMembershipMarkBonus of NewsRatingForGoldUser method and why it is not called?
DEBUGGING INFO :
   $membershipMark = $this->creator->membership_mark;
    \Log::info("Membership mark: " . $membershipMark);   // I see in log : Membership mark: G

   if (!isset($newsRatingMembershipMarkClasses[$membershipMark])) {
        throw new \Exception("Invalid membership mark: " . $membershipMark); // IS NOT CALLED
    }

    $ratingServiceClass = $newsRatingMembershipMarkClasses[$membershipMark];
    \Log::info("Rating service class: " . $ratingServiceClass); // I see in log : Rating service class: App\Library\Services\NewsRatingForGoldUser

   $ratingService = new $ratingServiceClass();
    \Log::info("Instance of class created: " . get_class($ratingService));  //  I see in log : Instance of class created: App\Library\Services\NewsRatingForGoldUser

    return $ratingService->calc($this->id);

But next message in log file is :
-1 NewsRatingForMemberUser calc is_int($news):

Which is called in calc method of NewsRatingForMemberUser.
I did not implement calc method in NewsRatingForGoldUser class.
Next message in log file :
-1 NewsRatingForMemberUser User getMembershipMarkBonus 0::

method getMembershipMarkBonus IS IMPLEMENTED in NewsRatingForGoldUser class - but it is not called!
Called method from NewsRatingForMemberUser and I can not catch why ?

You only define calc in the parent class and use self:: to invoke functions of the parent class. Using self:: will bypass inheritance
